# How can I import video into viewport?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, video, grease-pencil

I have already created a storyline, it is going to involve mixing film with 3D objects and possibly also using the grease pencil to create 2D animations on top of regular film too. If any of you know any great tutorials that are dumb proof, I would greatly appreciate it. I used to know how to import video in the old blender into the viewport and draw on top of it but I have yet to figure it out with the newest update.

Comment: Hello and welcome I cleaned up your post to go straight to the point. Asking for links on how to do X is considered off topic here, but directly asking how to solve X is ok. Could you rephrase your question on how to solve the specific issue you are encountering, rather than ask for pointers to tutorials.

Comment: Adding image empties works for video, so long as you set up the ending frame and the FPS right.